# What doe this syntax (.-body ...) mean in clojurescript/reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

This is from reagent [docs](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent).

```
(defn mountit []
  (r/render-component [childcaller]
                      (.-body js/document))) ; (.-body) what is this?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is JavaScript interop and accesses the `body` property of `document`, same as `document.body` in JavaScript. See: http://cljs.info/cheatsheet/. So the Reagent component will be mounted at the `body` element of the page.

Comment: I see, thank you. I suspected something of that nature.